# How to Apply CSS style to only two classes

Tags: html, css

I am working on web application in which html pages & css style are generated automatically. We are able to override CSS style to customize it. I tried to add a background to my home page so I wrote this css style:

```
.maintabitem-container.INXXJSB-l-d{
    background-image: url("../images/welcome_page_e-Life.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I got the background as expected, but this background was applied to all others pages in my application because they contain div like this:

```
<div class="maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d INXXJSB-h-f">
```

Is there a way to apply this style only to two classes ?

Comment: The 3rd class in that list, `INXXJSB-h-f, is that unique per page?

Comment: No it's a common class between all others pages

Comment: Simply like this: `[class='maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d']{background-image: url("../images/welcome_page_e-Life.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;`, but you should be aware of the orders of the 2 classes, if they are iinversed it won't work.

Comment: So `class="maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d INXXJSB-h-f"` is on all pages? If you write a selector for this, it will apply to all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an attribute selector like this:

```
[class='maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d']
```

Comment: [class='maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d']{
    background-image: url("../images/welcome_page_e-Life.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Like this ??

Comment: Yes exactly, Mark Steggles means that. But keep it mind if in other pages class contains same classes then it will apply for those pages as well.

Comment: @AmalAbidi But you should be aware of the orders of the 2 classes `'maintabitem-container INXXJSB-l-d'`, if they are iinversed in the HTML code like `'INXXJSB-l-d maintabitem-container'`, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add seperate class or id on desired section. But avoid this type of class `INXXJSB-l-d` `INXXJSB-h-f` because it can be change so you will get trouble because these class generated on runtime.

you can add diffrent class like `.exampleClass { background-image: url("../images/welcome_page_e-Life.jpg");}`